# C# ThreadLocal для Net3.5

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Имеется ли какая-нибудь альтернатива классу ThreadLocal в Net3.5 ? Этот класс появился в Net4.0.
А задача такая: требуется, чтобы значение приватного поля в класс жило отдельной жизнью для каждого потока (поле типа int, не static). Нужно в целях оптимизации поиска индекса в списке. При первом запросе запоминается найденный индекс, а при следующем запросе используется в качестве начального приближения. При этом разные потоки решают свои разные задачи и между собой не связаны. Если не отделять значение поля на потоки, то такая оптимизация теряет смысл.

Comment: Так вам надо не переменную на поток, а переменную на *задачу*. То есть вот надо вам решить 10 разных задач (и каждая делает свое дело), значит вам надо создать 10 экземпляров классов поиска путь даже по одним и тем же данным. А как запускаться эти классы поиска будут - в одном потоке или а разных, значения не имеет.

Comment: Пул объектов индексов вам может